# What is sha-256 padding?

Tags: sha

Studying a source code of one of the cpu miners I found this piece of code:

```
work->data[20] = 0x80000000;
```

Well, I asked the coded about it and his answer was:

*"Those values are part of standard SHA-2 padding"*

Googling "sha 2 padding" didn't help. Can you tell me what is this for?

I thought that **md5/sha256** functions simply take data and return hash.

I don't understand the "padding" concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find it documented in [RFC 4634 -- SHA and HMAC-SHA](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4634#page-6), section 4.1. Quoting from the introduction of part 4:

> As a summary, a "1" followed by a number of "0"s followed by a 64-bit or 128-bit integer are appended to the end of the message.

`0x80000000` is `10000000000000000000000000000000` in binary. Here is your *"1" followed by a number of "0"s*.

The reason is that SHA-256 processes the input by splitting it in blocks of fixed size. The last block might be smaller, so it is extended (padded) until its size matches the expected block size.

Answer (score 2):

Most modern cryptographic hash functions process messages in fixed-length blocks; all but the earliest hash functions include some sort of padding scheme. It is critical for cryptographic hash functions to employ termination schemes that prevent a hash from being vulnerable to length extension attacks. The rest can be found here [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29)

And by explaining with my own words: if you want to encrypt a text, the algorithm splits in into blocks of same size, if you don't have enough data at the last block the algorith adds 0's until it has the same size as the others.

Answer (score 2):

SHA-2 hashes are built upon the [Merkle-Damgård scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction). This means that the hash function is based on a one-way compression function which takes n + r bits of input and outputs r bits. Thus, the input must be partitioned into n-bit blocks such that the compression function can be applied to the each block with the output of the last round.

The padding is necessary such that the input can be partitioned into n-bit blocks. In particular a [Merkle-Damgård compliant padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction#MD-compliant_padding) is used for security reasons (see the link for details).

Answer (score 1):

Basically hash algorithms need a specific block size (fixed multiple of bytes) to work with.  Adding "padding" to the end of a message makes it reach the next multiple of block bytes.  But, you also need to know how big the actual message is as well.  By adding a 1-bit followed by enough 0-bits to the message you can then read back from the end of the message until you hit the first 1-bit, and that is the end of your message, so you know the size of it.